# AutoMapper configure to ignore null source member to custom struct type destination member

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes, an interface and a custom struct as shown below:

```cs
public class Source
{
    public decimal? Prop { get; set; }
}

public class Destination : IDestination
{
    public Destination()
    {
        Prop = new MyStruct(10);
    }
    public MyStruct Prop { get; set; }
}

public interface IDestination
{
    MyStruct Prop { get; set; }
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }
    public MyStruct(decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator MyStruct(decimal val) => new MyStruct(val);
}
```

What I want to achieve is to ignore any null value for `Prop` when mapping from `Source` to `Destination`. For example,

```cs
var obj1 = mapper.Map<IDestination>(new Source());
// obj1.Prop should be MyStruct(10), because null value in Source should be ignored

var obj2 = mapper.Map<IDestination>(new Source() { Prop = 20 });
// obj2.Prop should be MyStruct(20), because Prop is 20m so it is mapped
```

What I have now, is not working as expected:

```cs
// I have this conversion pair in a few classes so the mapping is not at the member level
CreateMap<decimal?, MyStruct>()
    .ConvertUsing((source, dest) => source ?? dest); // Use the destination value when source is null
CreateMap<Source, IDestination>()
    .ConstructUsing((_, _) => new Destination()) // This is actually constructed using the service locator but for simplicity I am using the concrete class constructor
    .ForAllMembers(options => options.Condition((_, _, sourceMember) =>
    {
        return sourceMember != null; // Only allow mapping of non null members
    }));
```

Fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/F1U9P2

Is there a correct way to configure AutoMapper so that it would ignore mapping of null values to a non-null property?

Edit:
In further testing, I found that

```cs
// This works
var obj1 = mapper.Map<Source, IDestination>(new Source(), new Destination());
// This does not work (when destination object is created by ConstructUsing)
var obj1 = mapper.Map<IDestination>(new Source());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AutoMapper, when a destination object is created using service locator, it treats the initial destination as null, and maps all the members using the default value `default(MyStruct)` when `UseDestinationValue` is not configured for the member, as written in the [source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/a00e68fc364f2f8c4987a9c19a45a6b2d7afe998/src/AutoMapper/Execution/TypeMapPlanBuilder.cs#L350).

The solution would be to configure `.UseDestinationValue()` on the member mapping expression.

In my case, there are many models having members that should be mapped from `decimal?` to `MyStruct`, so I have an extension method instead.

```cs
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> UseDestinationValueForKnownMemberTypes<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> mappingExpression)
{
    mappingExpression.ForAllMembers(options =>
    {
        if (IsKnownType(options.DestinationMember))
        {
            options.UseDestinationValue();
        }
    });
    return mappingExpression;
}

private static bool IsKnownType(MemberInfo destinationMember)
{
    var propertyType = destinationMember is PropertyInfo p ? p.PropertyType : null;
    // Use a static hashset to handle multiple types 
    return propertyType == typeof(MyStruct);
}

CreateMap<Source, IDestination>()
    .UseDestinationValueForKnownMemberTypes();
```

Comment: You either pass a destination object to `Map`, or you don't, the service locator is irrrelevant.

Comment: The object you see in the example is actually deeply nested in another object and for that matter I do pass the destination object when I call to `Map`. When the nested object is mapped, a new instance is created from the service locator and AutoMapper treats that case as `initialDestination == null`, which is shown in the link to the source code, to have a workaround of configuring `UseDestinationValue`.

Comment: Again, irrelevant, if a new instance is created, there is no passed object to be used.

Comment: If a new instance is created from service injection, it already has the default values for all the value type members, which should not be overwritten by AutoMapper with the `default(Struct)` value.

Comment: You cannot map _into_ value types because of boxing and copying. Both can easily happen for multiple reasons. Everything works as expected.

Comment: It is not mapping into value types, it is just the mapping of one object to another, with the nested destination object being created by service injection, and the value type member is overwritten with a default of the value type.

Comment: Why is that? Nothing you've said here answers that :)

Comment: Here is a simple [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HlWwNR) to demonstrate the behaviour.

Comment: You need `mapper.Map(new SourceRoot() { Obj = new Source() }, new DestinationRoot { Obj = new Destination()})`. The service locator thing is unrelated to what's going on.

Comment: Fair enough, this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NdJmxL) is the closest thing to what the actual scenario is, which I can't seem to find a way to make it work without using the workaround in this solution.

Comment: That's certainly smth else :) Maybe AutoMapper.Collection can help with that one.

Comment: That is interesting, I will look into the package to see if it helps to solve this. Thank :)

Answer (score 2):

You should also provide an explict mapping from `decimal?` to `MyStruct` and use `.ConvertUsing()` to provide a manual mapping method. Probably [something like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e0mAKN):

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
        CreateMap<decimal?, MyStruct>()
            .ConvertUsing((source, dest, context) =>
            {
                return source.HasValue
                    ? new MyStruct(source.Value)
                    : dest;
            });
    }
}
```

Due to the fact, that we either take the original value or create a `new MyStruct(source.Value)` you could also remove your implicit operator from your class above if the only used place would be within AutoMapper.

#### Update

Due to the additional mapping from the interface this profile would have the [desired behaviour](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GUb22m):

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, IDestination>()
            .ConvertUsing((source, dest, context) => {
                dest ??= new Destination();

                if(source.Prop.HasValue)
                    dest.Prop = source.Prop.Value;

                return dest;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the explicit mapping from `decimal?` to `MyStruct` and a `.ConvertUsing()` which when I debugged, the value of `dest` is always `new MyStruct(0)` instead of the actual destination member value.

Comment: [Works on my internet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e0mAKN)

Comment: Apparently this mapping works for a concrete class but not for interface, which is what I'm actually doing and I have oversimplified the reproducible scenario. Can you look at my updated question or checkout [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F1U9P2) to see the issue I'm experiencing?

Comment: The updated answer is only writing a manual mapping for the members in the destination. The thing is the destination object should be created by the service locator and the property mappings be done by automapper.

Comment: So, your example code is wrong and you always have an existing instance of `IDestination` and that should be mapped by calling e.g. `mapper.Map<Source, IDestination>(source, dest);`?

Comment: My example code is much more simplified version of what I was actually doing. It is very deeply nested and a lot of the mappings are created from the dependency injection. I have finally found a solution after going through AutoMapper's source code, which is to call `UseDestinationValue()` when the member type being mapped is recognised, it prevents AutoMapper from using `default(MyStruct)` when mapping the member.

Comment: Specifically [this line](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/a00e68fc364f2f8c4987a9c19a45a6b2d7afe998/src/AutoMapper/Execution/TypeMapPlanBuilder.cs#L350) always uses the `default(MyStruct)` even when the destination is created using service locator, which should mean that the initial destination is not null.

Comment: Great you solved it.  So write it as answer to your question and mark it as accepted.